# How do I configure Undertow's SSL / cipher suite?

Tags: java, http2, undertow

When I try to view my http2 webpage in Chrome or Firefox, I currently get an error page saying: "ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY"

This apparently means that the cypher suite that my Undertow webserver is using is not accepted by the browser due to being too insecure.

How do I set the TLS level for Undertow and select which cipher it should use?
If I understand correctly from googling around, it has little to nothing to do with how I created my certificate and outside of HTTP2 the ssl connection does work fine.

Comment: Please show your `undertow` config.

Comment: gf_, i dont have an undertow config because I'm using it outside of jboss

Answer (score 0):

by using `Undertow.builder()` what you want is `setSocketOption` method like this:

```
Undertow.builder()//add your build code like https listener, server options, etc
    .setSocketOption(Options.SSL_ENABLED_PROTOCOLS, Sequence.of("TLSv1.2","TLSv1.3"))
    .setSocketOption(Options.SSL_ENABLED_CIPHER_SUITES,Sequence.of(// your cipher suites))
```

the above call will disable all TLS versions below 1.2 and only enable the cipher suites you want, `setSocketOption` works on XNIO level which is the transport layer of undertow, `Options` and `Sequence` classes also come from XNIO.

Notice that I've added TLS 1.3 which is the latest version as of time of writing and supported by all evergreen browsers(but not IE). be sure to use a provider that supports it though, if you're using JDK SSL provider then make sure you're using java 11+., otherwise see your provider's docs, a SSL provider that supports TLS1.3 is google Conscrypt found [here](https://github.com/google/conscrypt).

One thing to be aware of is that setting enabled cipher suites works if your SSL provider supports that, in my case I use google Conscrypt but they don't support setting enabled cipher suites for TLS1.3, in their docs they say they ignore the option but in my case the undertow server fully stopped working so please consult your provider docs or better just set enabled protocols as that's what you probably want.